# MVC6 Globally scoped value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to pull a websites name for the database here is the model:

```
 public class Store
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string StoreName { get; set; }
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is only make one database request for this information.

This `SiteName`is currently used in the Navbar but will probably be used elsewhere.

I've created a ViewComponent for the Navbar :

```
public class NavbarViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private IStoreRepository _storeRepository;
        private string _storeName;
        public NavbarViewComponent(IStoreRepository storeRepository)
        {
            _storeRepository = storeRepository;
            _storeName = _storeRepository.GetStoreById(1).StoreName;
        }
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View((object)_storeName);
        }
    }
```

Accessed like so:

```
@model string
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="App" asp-action="Index">@Model</a> <!-- Here -->
...
```

The issue is that every time a page is loaded a call is made to the database to get it, which is understandable. However I'm not sure on how to have the `SiteName` accessible by **one** call to the repository and it stored for future use.

I thought about loading it into a session variable but really it should be persistent 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

The information below is a good idea if this is a variable used across the application.  However, in this case, the question is about a dynamic store name.  The ending section would not work here.

One of the ways I have dealt with a multi-tenant application is to make a wrapper function that gets the store name.  Basically, store the names in the HttpContext cache and use the wrapper function to either get the value from cache or if its a miss, get it from the database.

```
public string GetStoreNameById(int id){
   var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
   //if no httpContext, just return from the db
   //rare but could throw a NullRefEx
   if(httpContext == null) return db.GetStore(id).Name;
   //build your key
   var key = string.format("Store-{0}", id);
   //if we get a cache miss, add the item from the db
   if(httpContext.Items[key] == null){
      var storeName = db.GetStore(id).Name;
      //note: there are overloads of this function for expiry times, etc.
      httpContext.Items.Add(key, storeName);
   }
   //return the value
   return httpContext.Items[key];
}
```

---

**Good for a non-dynamic variable**

This sounds like it should be a setting in the web.config.  Quick to get the value and is accessible from any assembly running in the application.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StoreName" value="My Store"/>
</appSettings>
```

And to fetch this value:

```
var storeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StoreName"];
```

Comment: This is a good answer and storing it in the config is probably the best way to go, so I'll mark this as the correct answer. I might not need to even have a DB call for the info. Since each "Store" is deployed in its own container on separate domains. I could just manipulate the config.json on deployment. Thanks Tommy

Comment: @Jezzabeanz - I just noticed you are on .NET 5, can you provide an edit for any differences between pre version 5 and version 5?  This should work for v 4.6 and less, but not sure about the 5 syntax.

Comment: @Tommy: are you sure the Items container is a best choice here for an app wide setting?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how to manipulate the config.json programmatically yet (I've only been trying out V5 and MVC 6 for a few hours).

Comment: @WiktorZychla - how so?  I'd be glad to entertain a better thought!